# EKS to AKS workload migration

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, azure-aks

We have a project where we need to migrate EKS ( Elastic Kubernetes Services ) clusters to AKS ( Azure Kubernetes Services ). What are the steps that we need to follow to successfully migrate those clusters.

With some research found that we can only migrate though backing up kubernetes cluster on AWS storage bucket and then moving it to a blob storage on Azure and then configuring AKS settings.

Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the tools like **[Velero](https://velero.io/)** to Backup & restore the Kubernetes cluster.

i have written the Article you can refer the same : https://faun.pub/clone-migrate-data-between-kubernetes-clusters-with-velero-e298196ec3d8

You can leverage the plugin with [Velero](https://velero.io/plugins/) tools as per requirement **EKS** & **AKS** both supported.